# Run querySelector using a cell reference

Tags: css, excel, vba, queryselector

i have a column of cells refer below.
currently in a webscrape macro i have 7 lines of VBA code using
simple If Then Else End If syntax.
can i utilise the string values of these cells to save me from having to manually
write 7 lines of code.

```
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='26']")
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='23']")
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='19']")
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='16']")
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='12']")
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='9']")
IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='5']")
```

Comment: `IEDoc.querySelector("a[rel^='" & theCell.Value & "']")`

Comment: Tim, i had tried all manner of combo's. this looks good. thanks for your answer. i will go and test. Cheers.

Comment: Tim, works like a charm. BTW just getting to the values in that column took me a couple of days. Can't thank you enough.